# How can I make Atom my default editor when I open a file from terminal?

Tags: xcode, terminal, atom-editor

Every time I open a file from the terminal it opens the file in Xcode.

`open hashing.md` then Xcode opens. I don't want it to open in Xcode.

How can I make my terminal open files in Atom instead?

I'm on a Mac, Monterey, 12.1.

(I'm at the point where I just want to uninstall Xcode, but, who knows, I may need it in the future.)

I see this suggestion from someone, but I don't know how to do it. How do I "add the following to my ~/.bashrc file?" What does that mean? Where is my ~/.bashrc file and how do I add to it?

Add the following to your ~/.bashrc file:
export EDITOR="/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"

Answer (score 0):

Open finder and look for a file with the extension you want to open using atom, ".md" for example.

Right click on it and go to "Get info". You should see an "Open With" tab. Click on it, choose atom and click on the "Change all" button. That will make it the default option to open any ".md" file.

In case you just want to open a certain file with atom, use the `-a` flag with the `open` command.

```
~% open -a atom file.md
```